# Merge Chromium and Chrome cache dirs

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, cache

As the title says, is it possible to point both `Chrome` and `Chromium` cache directories to the same directory? I mean, is it a simple link between the two directories enough or it will raise problems?

Answer (score 2):

Even though Chrome is based on the Chromium they're still distinct and considerably different application. Their releases are not usually based on the same state of the common part of their code base.

With that in mind I'm not sure if this is possible. It may work but it definitely wouldn't work reliably as the two applications may use different cache formats.